Structure of a commutative ring with one prime ideal.
For any maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of a commutative ring $A$, the ring $A/\mathfrak m^n$ has only one prime ideal, namely $\mathfrak m+\mathfrak m^n$. For example the ring $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$. I cannot think of other type of examples, and I am trying to prove the converse: If $A$ has a unique prime ideal $\mathfrak p$, is $A$ isomorphic to some $B/\mathfrak m^n$, where $\mathfrak m$ is maximal in $B$? We can start from the fact that every element in the prime $\mathfrak p$ of $A$ is nilpotent...
Note that this is trivial if $A$ were to be Noetherian, as the finitely generated ideal $\mathfrak p$ in $A$ is nilpotent, so $A\simeq A/\mathfrak p^n$ for some $n$.

Judging by the content and timing of your question with the duplicate, it suggests that maybe collaboration with classmates may be called for...

@rschwieb That must be a huge coincidence - I came up with this question just at random when I was flipping through exercises in A&M chapter 1…
